Insert into empty MongoDB collection using informatica power center
I have established a MongoDB ODBC connection and trying to load from Oracle db to MongoDB collection using informatica power center.
When collection is empty workflow fails and doesn't load anything. When I insert q sample record manually and run the workflow it inserts the data correctly.
Is there any way to load data to empty collection using powercenter?
I am looking for a way where all the data gets loaded without manually inserting sample record

I'm not familiar with MongoDB Collections - but it looks as if the collection is not existing when Informatica tries to insert data. Perhaps there is some extra setting to create it if it does not exist? Perhaps it is created when you insert manually?
